# Why are the fighting me? Skyrim Special Edition-Xbox one

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-one

So I just got done killing a dragon with Farkas, So I go back to the companions, and they start fighting me! I did nothing wrong, and im very confused- is it a bug? It’s only two people. Farkas and his twin brother seem cool, there just staring at me- what do I do? I’m playing Skyrim on Xbox. This is random-but for some reason, I’m in love with Farkas, anyone else?